# http4s-request-signer_2.13 dependency is not downloaded from central repository

Tags: scala, sbt, maven-3, github-package-registry, github-packages

As I build scala project using >sbt assembly , I am getting the below error. Should I configure anything to resolve this issue?

```
[info] Strategy 'rename' was applied to 6 files (Run the task at debug level to see details)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading pl.abankowski:http4s-request-signer_2.13:0.4.3
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/localpl.abankowski/http4s-request-signer_2.13/0.4.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/pl/abankowski/http4s-request-signer_2.13/0.4.3/http4s-request-signer_2.13-0.4.3.pom
[error]   not found: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/pl/abankowski/http4s-request-signer_2.13/0.4.3/http4s-request-signer_2.13-0.4.3.pom
[error]   unauthorized: https://maven.pkg.github.com/abankowski/http-request-signer/pl/abankowski/http4s-request-signer_2.13/0.4.3/http4s-request-signer_2.13-0.4.3.pom
[error] Error downloading pl.abankowski:http-request-signer-core_2.13:0.4.3
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/localpl.abankowski/http-request-signer-core_2.13/0.4.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/pl/abankowski/http-request-signer-core_2.13/0.4.3/http-request-signer-core_2.13-0.4.3.pom
[error]   not found: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/pl/abankowski/http-request-signer-core_2.13/0.4.3/http-request-signer-core_2.13-0.4.3.pom
[error]   unauthorized: https://maven.pkg.github.com/abankowski/http-request-signer/pl/abankowski/http-request-signer-core_2.13/0.4.3/http-request-signer-core_2.13-0.4.3.pom
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:258)
[err



lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalacOptions ++= List("-Ymacro-annotations", "-Yrangepos", "-Wconf:cat=unused:info", "-language:reflectiveCalls"),
  scalafmtOnCompile := true,
  scalafixOnCompile := true,
  resolvers ++= List(
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
    Resolver.githubPackages("abankowski", "http-request-signer")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's [not published](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=abankowski) at Maven central. It's in [Github Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/introduction-to-github-packages) here: https://github.com/abankowski/http-request-signer

Tab "Packages": https://github.com/abankowski?tab=packages&repo_name=http-request-signer

To work with Github Packages via sbt you can use this [plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Using-Plugins.html): https://github.com/djspiewak/sbt-github-packages

So add to `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.codecommit" % "sbt-github-packages" % "0.5.3")
```

[Add](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html) to `build.sbt`

```
resolvers += Resolver.githubPackages("abankowski")

  // this is default so could be omitted
githubTokenSource := TokenSource.Environment("GITHUB_TOKEN") 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "pl.abankowski" %% "http4s-request-signer" % "0.4.3",
  "pl.abankowski" %% "http-request-signer-core" % "0.4.3",
)
```

Add environment variable (e.g. in `~/.profile`)

```
export GITHUB_TOKEN=...................
```

You can get the token at https://github.com/settings/tokens

The token should have permission "Download packages from GitHub Package Registry" `read:packages`.

---

There is also an option to configure the token in `~/.gitconfig`

```
githubTokenSource := TokenSource.GitConfig("github.token")
```

`.gitconfig`

```
[github]
  token = .........................
```

Comment: It is working as expected