# How to add Github maven registry into build.sbt

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, github-package-registry, github-packages

I want to add a scala Library into my `build.sbt` dependencies. [Here is the sample package](https://github.com/gjuoun/sbt-github-package-demo/packages/409831), and it publishes in Github registry.
This library is not from the official maven repository, I could not find it in [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/gjuoun). I think it could not install in there.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>gjuoun</groupId>
  <artifactId>hellopackage_2.13</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And then, I find it should belong to `ghcr.io`, so I add this line to my `build.sbt`.

```
resolvers += "hellopackage" at "http://ghcr.io/gjuoun/hellopackage"
```

It does not work at all. I could not use it. I am looking for a better to install this package by using `resolvers` without `addSbtPlugin`. (I don't want to use `pom.xml` if possible)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74126937/http4s-request-signer-2-13-dependency-is-not-downloaded-from-central-repository

Comment: Could you be more specific when you say "it doesn't work"? What are SBT logs? Do you see an attempt to retrieve the artifact from ghcr.io? Any error code/message?

Comment: @GaëlJ The error is about the project can't find the library. It sounds like I did not add the dependency correctly. ```http://ghcr.io/gjuoun/hellopackage``` is wrong, but I don't know how to add this library as my dependency in ```build.sbt``` .

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thank you. so if I want to install the library locally, I have to use my PAT all the time. Is that correct?

Comment: @JoeYo Yes, you have to use a token (see the answer linked). Either the one you usually use or you can create a separate one with necessary minimal permissions for this task. After first successful build the library jar will be cached locally, sbt will use it in the first turn instead of github registry untill something happens to the cache.

Comment: @JoeYo You can always put a jar to `lib` as well.

Comment: @JoeYo Why don't you want to use sbt plugin?

Comment: @JoeYo it could be helpful for future readers if you copy paste in your message the complete log of error SBT is giving you

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thanks alot for your help, I finally decide to use plugin, I was spending time searching for install packages without passing PAT. Anyway, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440202/how-to-add-github-maven-registry-into-build-sbt?noredirect=1#comment131427509_74440202) works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can use Daniel Spiewak's sbt plugin [sbt-github-packages](https://github.com/djspiewak/sbt-github-packages).

See details in [http4s-request-signer_2.13 dependency is not downloaded from central repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74126937/http4s-request-signer-2-13-dependency-is-not-downloaded-from-central-repository)

- If you don't want to use sbt plugins  and you're interested only in building your project but not publishing it (to Github registry) then you can just add to `build.sbt`

```scala
// specifying repo is optional: "_"
resolvers += "Another maven repo" at "https://maven.pkg.github.com/gjuoun/_"

credentials += Credentials(
  "GitHub Package Registry",
  "maven.pkg.github.com",
  "_", // user is ignored
  "ghp_YOUR_GITHUB_TOKEN"
)

libraryDependencies += "gjuoun" %% "hellopackage" % "0.1.6"
```

That's basically what the plugin does.

For security reasons it's better not to hardcode the token in `build.sbt` but for example put it into environment variable

```scala
credentials += Credentials(
  "GitHub Package Registry",
  "maven.pkg.github.com",
  "_",
  sys.env("GITHUB_TOKEN")
)
```

You can check that without `credentials` sbt will not be able to build your project.

The thing is that although manually you can download a JAR from Github in your browser without authentification (and put it into `lib`), this doesn't mean that Github allow reading, resolving, downloading programmatically via API (sbt, ivy, coursier) without authentification.

You need authentification only the first time. Then JAR will be cached locally in `~/.cache/coursier/v1/https/maven.pkg.github.com/gjuoun/_/gjuoun/hellopackage_2.13/0.1.6/` and will be taken from there further on.

Several quotes:

[A valid Github token shouldn't always be mandatory #28](https://github.com/djspiewak/sbt-github-packages/issues/28)

> GitHub requires a token even for read-only access to packages.

[Credentials should remain optional #34](https://github.com/djspiewak/sbt-github-packages/pull/34)

> So the problem I have with this is the fact that resolution from GitHub Packages also requires a token. You can't just download a package unauthenticated, meaning that credentials are necessary at all times regardless of whether or not you're publishing. Honestly, this is a thing that GitHub needs to fix.